# Want to use UIAlertController inside an Alamofire reponseJSON block

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, uialertcontroller

The UIAlertControllers are not being executed or are not being displayed. If i solely write a print statement then there's output in the console but now the print statements are also not being executed(if i write them along with the UIAlertControllers like in the code i wrote below).

```
 Alamofire.request(some_url, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{
                response in

                let json = JSON(response.result.value)

                print(json)
                self.eventid = json[0]["EventRegID"].stringValue

                if !json[0]["AuthKeyError"].exists(){
                    if !json[0]["ExceptionOccured"].exists(){
                        if !json[0]["RegistrationFailed"].exists() {
                            if !json[0]["EventInHold"].exists() {
                                if json[0]["RegistrationSuccess"].exists() {
                                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: json[0]["RegistrationSuccess"].stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
                                    let no1Action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                                        print("The user has registered successfully")
                                    }
                                    alertController.addAction(no1Action)
                                }
                                else{

                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Event is on hold.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                let no2Action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                                    print("The event is on hold.")
                                }
                                let yes2Action = UIAlertAction(title: "GO", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "bullshit", sender: self)
                                }
                                alertController.addAction(no2Action)
                                alertController.addAction(yes2Action)
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            print("Registration failed due to connection issues. Please login.")
                            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Registration failed", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let no3Action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                                print("The registration failed")
                            }
                            alertController.addAction(no3Action)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        print("There's some problem with the database")
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Some problem with the server", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let no4Action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                            print("The user has registered successfully")
                        }
                        alertController.addAction(no4Action)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("AuthKeyError")
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Auth key error", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let no5Action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                        print("AAUTH KEY ERROR")
                    }
                    alertController.addAction(no5Action)
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            print("not ok")

        }



    }
```

Comment: Where are you presenting the alert controller? I don't see any calls to present.

Comment: the many `if-else` statements not look very nice - you should improve it. you can use a switch case for example. for example with response [handling chaining](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#chained-response-handlers). can you post examples (one or two) of your error JSON

Comment: you can use the response validation for this. doc and examples [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-validation) and [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#response-validation)

Comment: and here the tests: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Tests/ValidationTests.swift

Comment: Yes @Samantha that was the problem. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I'll change the code @muescha. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you need to present the alertcontroller after `addAction`

```
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

maybe you have to present it in a new operation

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
   presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I really think that multithreading is evil, and swift with its easy closures makes it even worse. I guess this is the twentieth question this week that has a similar solution as yours, e.g. someone wants to do something in the UI from a non-main-thread :-)

Comment: Thanks @Retterdesdialogs for the code and suggestions, it solved my problem.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen You are absolutely right. I just mentioned that, because maybe he want to change to another controller after the request. Also i don't see any delegate protocols and the implementation don't look that professional, so maybe he will stuck because the main thread is blocked for a reason.

Comment: @RohitDulam if this answer solved you problem then mark the answer as accepted. klick on they gray checkmark on the left side.